# Icinga2 node setup fails. "Too many arguments. At most 0 arguments must be specifed"

Tags: linux, ansible, icinga2

Icinga Version: r2.10.3-1

I am trying to use an ansible playbook to automate my icinga client configuration. When i run the icinga2 node setup command in my playbook I get the error I mentioned in the title. "Too many arguments. At most 0 arguments must be specified". Here is the part of the playbook which gives the error:

> - name: Run node setup
>   become: yes
>   shell: |
>   icinga2 node setup 
>   --ticket {{ icinga2_ticket.stdout_lines[0] }} 
>   --cn {{ icinga2_cn }} 
>   --zone {{ icinga2_zone }} 
>   --endpoint {{ icinga2_endpoint }} 
>   --parent_host {{ icinga2_parent_host }} 
>   --parent_zone {{ icinga2_parent_zone }} 
>   -- trustedcert {{ icinga2_pki_path }}ca.crt 
>   {{ '--accept-config' if icinga2_accept_config }} 
>   {{ '--accept-commands' if icinga2_accept_config }} 
>   {{ '--enable-confd' if icinga2_enable_confd }} 
>   args:
>   creates: "{{ icinga2_pki_path }}/{{ icinga2_cn }}.crt"

The error is confuisng me because I know the icinga2 node setup command requires arguments to work correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a space in `-- trustedcert`? Should it be there?

Comment: That was the issue. There wasn't supposed to be a space there . Thanks for you help i didn't even notice